# Windows CE 6.0 + SQL Server Compact 3.5 = Slow Data Access

Tags: optimization, sql-server-ce, windows-ce, motorola, data-access

I'am used mobile [Motorola MC-2180](http://rms.lu/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/MC2100-Spec-Sheet-1211.pdf) device with Windows Embedded CE 6.0 + SQL Server Compact 3.5. Databases are on the memory card Kingston 8 GB 10 class.

**Problem:** Database have 1000000 rows and one cluster index and one non-cluster index. When I use query to database first time (query used index) - query runs very slowly (~120 min).

It is possible to accelerate or to organize data so that the query execution time was quick (~5 sec)?

**In summary:** we want to make an inventory of stock with this device using its own database products. Network access is not.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello Maxim, and welcome to StackOverflow! what have you tried so far? can we see some code and example data? it's kind of hard to optimise a database and/or query when you have no idea what it does exactly

Comment: Does your database come from a desktop system? What do you mean by "first time" ?

Comment: The database is a simple table with fields (IdRow int not null, IdBarcode int not null, Name char(100) not null). Clustery IdRow index and non-clustered index on IdBarcode. The table has 1000000 records. When you first access the table (select * from myTable where IdBarcode = 123) from a mobile device to cache the index and this is a very long time (from 2 hours). This situation is unacceptable. How to speed up caching the index?

Answer (score 0):

The device you're using does not have a very good hardware configuration (it has only 128 to 256 MB of RAM). Better would be using something like **MC45** or **MC3100 Series**.
Anyway, you might want try to move the .sdf file to the device's ROM memory, this might speed up your time, but forget about making it 5 seconds.

Ever thought if the .sdf MUST have all those 1Mi rows. Couldn't you segregate the data?

If you want to exchange knowledge, I'd be happy to pass my experience along!

Comment: At the moment the situation described in my answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the customer does not intend in the near future to purchase more efficient devices.

The memory of the device is limited. Database size about 2 GB and every year will increase by approximately 500 MB. It was therefore decided raspolojit the database on the microSD (class 10).

On the date you place try the following algorithm:

1. All tables above 1000000 rows are divided into table with number of rows not more than 500000.
2. Implemented in the software of the mobile device function cache (one query for each table in the database). This though time consuming, but is required only once and after the cache data is accessed quickly.
3. Synchronization with a remote database (to add new information to the database of the mobile device) is performed using the mobile device. In this case, caching is not required - the database is updated directly on the device.